# Ruby on rails NoMethodError active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these models

```
class Auto < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :marca
  belongs_to :modelo
  belongs_to :cliente  
end

class Cliente < ApplicationRecord  
  has_many :autos
end

class Marca < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :modelos
  has_many :autos
end

class Modelo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :marca
  has_many :autos
end
```

and this index view

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="autos">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Cliente</th>
    <th>Marca</th>
    <th>Modelo</th>
    <th>Placas</th>
  </tr>
  <% @auto.each do |auto| %>
  <tr>
      <td><%= auto.id %></td>
      <td><%= auto.cliente.nombre %></td>
      <td><%= auto.marca.nombre%></td>
      <td><%= auto.modelo.nombre %></td>
      <td><%= auto.placas %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

and this in my autos controller

```
def show
 @auto = Auto.find(params[:id])    
end

def index
 @auto = Auto.all    
end
```

the problem is that show me this error:
undefined method `nombre' for nil:NilClass in this line:

`<td><%= auto.cliente.nombre %></td>`

rarely at show view where I call

```
@auto.cliente.nombre
```

works fine, can you help me? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `<td><%= auto.cliente.nombre %></td>` doesn't work because `auto.cliente` is `nil`, and you cannot call that method `nombre` on `nil`. Perhaps one of your auto objects doesn't have an associated client?

To see how this happens, try running `nil.hello` in Ruby and you should see a NoMethodError with the error message `undefined method 'hello' for nil:NilClass`.

Answer (score 0):

`auto.cliente.try(:nombre)` will save you from error if you by chance allow auto without cliente.